# Select a particular slicer from list of slicers value

Tags: excel, vba

Considering my all slicers a selected in the SlicerCaches, this code still is not selecting the correct slicer:

```vb
Dim sli As SlicerItem
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sub_Function__Div_5")
    For Each sli In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sub_Function__Div_5").SlicerItems
        If Not sli.Name = "America" Then sli.Selected = False
       Next
End With
```

I am expecting except America, other countries should not be selected
Can anyone please help?

Comment: There is no `sli.Selected = True` there

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Dim sli As SlicerItem
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sub_Function__Div_5")
    .SlicerItems("America").Selected = True 'show the item of interest
    For Each sli In .SlicerItems
        If sli.Name <> "America" Then sli.Selected = False
    Next
End With
```

...as long as you're not using a Data Model as a source for the PT (ie. it's just based on a Range)